# react-native fetch data from REST Api fails

Tags: rest, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I want to fetch data from a different Server with a REST API.

I do this:

```
    return fetch('http://localhost:9000/processes')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            return responseJson;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

In the render function I have this:

```
       {JSON.stringify(getProcesses().Prozess1) }
```

and this

```
        {JSON.stringify(getProcesses()) }
```

no one of thesse two examples returns something

The rest API should return this:

```
{
  "Prozess1": "Hallo ich bin ein Prozess"
}
```

whats my problem in this case

Comment: `getProcesses()` is that asynchronous action which returns a promise?

Comment: Yes getProcesses ist the Funktion which shoukd Return the json

Comment: fetch() is async so it shouldn't return anything. fetch().then() is a promise, which means whenever fetch completes, do the following. So refactor your code a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React `render()` is a pure function of `state` and `props`. You shouldn't try to perform asynchronous API calls or modify state inside render; so if you need to use fetched data in your components, you can either load it in the parent component and pass it as `props`, or perform the fetch inside the component and save the result in your component `state`.

Here's an example of a possible, simplified implementation using the component `state`:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getProcesses = this.getProcesses.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProcesses();
  }

  async getProcesses() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/processes');
      if (response.ok) {
        const processes = await response.json();
        this.setState({processes}); //this will trigger the render function with the new state
      } else {
        console.error(response.status);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {processes} = this.state;
    return (
      <Text>
        {processes && processes.Prozess1}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```